# How to grab Outlook Conversation Id in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm sending mass emails from a spreadsheet in Excel, using the Outlook reference library for my VBA code.

When I send the email, I need to save the conversation ID number to a cell in the sheet. How do I return this property from the email to excel?

Comment: If you have a `MailItem` variable set, you should be able to read the `ConversationID` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once email is sent out, search sent folder and then grab the conversation ID.

Example here search by subject `If olItem.Subject = "0m3r" Then` print ConvID to cell A1

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvID()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olSentMail As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object ' Mail Item
    Dim ConvID As Object ' ConversationID

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olSentMail = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For Each ConvID In olSentMail.Items
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then ' ignores MeetingItem or ReportItem
            If TypeName(ConvID) = "MailItem" Then
            Set olItem = ConvID
                If olItem.Subject = "0m3r" Then
                  Debug.Print olItem.ConversationID
                  Range("A1").Value = olItem.ConversationID
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I know this is 4yrs old but it has helped me! Was looking for a quick and simple method to get the conversation id's...

Comment: another example @alowflyingpig https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196066/4539709

Comment: @0m3r that is also VERY useful. Was looking for something to move emails according to conversation. I help maintain a shared inbox so this example will come in very useful. Thank you!!